# Ag-grid es2015 compatibility

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to use the ag-grid enterprise version of 24 with Tsconfig as es2015, the build is getting freezed, but when using es6 the build is success. Can someone let me
Know if ag-grid is es2015 compatible?

Comment: They have only mentioned ECMA 6... https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/npm/